# Remove repeating text values in cells in google chart table

Tags: google-visualization

Is it possible to remove repeating text data in a Google visualization chart table?Looking for quick suggestions

FYI Following is an example of my question.!

In the column 'Test Plan Name'..I want to remove the repeating names... Can it possible?
Thank You

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKjk7.jpg

Comment: What would you like the table to look like with the duplicate data removed?  Do you have sorting enabled, and if so how do you want to handle duplicate data that is split up when the data is resorted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I searched I couldn't find any option to eliminate duplicate values. But we can count the null and duplicate values.Also we can perform `joins,avg,sum,min,max` on a google table chart's column values.
 This [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference) explains about this. Hope this will help you.